# How do we determine whether a heuristic function is better than another?

Tags: comparison, search, a-star, admissible-heuristic, heuristic-functions

I am trying to solve a maze puzzle using the A* algorithm. I am trying to analyze the algorithm based on different applicable heuristic functions.

Currently, I explored the Manhattan and Euclidean distances. Which other heuristic functions are available? How do we compare them? How do we know whether a heuristic function is better than another?

Answer (score 3):

In the A* algorithm, at each iteration, a node is chosen which minimizes a certain function, called the *evaluation function*, which, in the case of A*, is defined as

$$f(n)=g(n)+h(n)$$

where $g(n)$ is the length (or cost) of the cheapest path from the start node to the current node $n$ and $h(n)$ is the heuristic function that estimates the *cost* of the cheapest path from current node $n$ to goal node.

There is potentially more than one path to the goal from a given node $n$. However, one of these paths is the cheapest path. An [**admissible heuristic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) function is a [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) function that does **not** overestimate the cost to reach the goal node, that is, it estimates a cost to reach a goal that is smaller or equal to the cheapest path from $n$, which is denoted by $h^*(n)$. Therefore, an admissible heuristic $h$ satisfies $h(n) \leq h^*(n), \forall n$. Given that the goal is to find the cheapest path from a start to a goal node, intuitively, an admissible heuristic is an *optimistic* predictive function.

A* is guaranteed to find the optimal solution (or path) if it uses an admissible heuristic. In section 2.4 of the book [Principles of Artificial Intelligence](https://books.google.ch/books?id=4JwN5DTpcqkC&pg=PA72&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1982), Nils J. Nilsson provides the proof of this fact.

However, not all admissible heuristics give the same information, so not all admissible heuristics are equally efficient. For instance, a heuristic function that is trivially admissible is $h(n) = 0, \forall n$. However, in this case, the only actual information that is used to choose the next node to expand is only based on $g(n)$, that is, $f(n) = g(n)$. [This evaluation function corresponds to the evaluation function of the uniform-cost search algorithm](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/9182/2444), which is an uninformed-search algorithm (as opposed to A*, which, nonetheless, is considered an informed-search algorithm).

Which admissible heuristic is thus more informed? Consider two versions of A*, each with a different *admissible* heuristic function

$$
f_1(n) = g_1(n) + h_1(n)
$$

and

$$
f_2(n) = g_1(n) + h_2(n)
$$

where $h_1(n) \leq h^*(n), \forall n$ and $h_2(n) \leq h^*(n), \forall n$. Then A* with the evaluation function $f_1$ is more informed than A* with $f_2$ if, for all non-goal nodes $n$, $h_1(n) > h_2(n)$. See [section 2.4.4. of the cited book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=4JwN5DTpcqkC&pg=PA72&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) where an example that attempts to show this is given.

The admissibility of a heuristic depends on the problem. For example, in the case of the [Fifteen Puzzle problem](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2000/AAAI00-212.pdf), both Manhattan and the Hamming distances are admissible heuristics. However, in other problems, these distances might not [induce](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2704941/168764) an admissible heuristic.